# Ruby on Rails - do I need to manually set BUNDLE_GEMFILE each time I switch projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm relatively new to rails/docker. I'm using a docker container to maintain my development environment, and working on several projects under /apps. In my dockerfile I've defined the BUNDLE_PATH and BUNDLE_BIN directories (ubuntu base image):

```
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_BIN=/bundle/bin
```

I am then using a volume to store the bundle files, and a bind mount so that I can use sublime text to work on the application. I'm using a docker-compose file to accomplish this.

```
version: '3'

services:

  rails_app:
    container_name: rails_app
    command: bash
    working_dir: /apps
    environment:
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 'true'
      RAILS_ENV: development
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile_ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/apps/
      - bundle_gems:/bundle
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 80:80

volumes:
  bundle_gems:
```

I run

```
docker-compose run --service-ports rails_app bash
```

to bring up my container. I understand eventually I can use entrypoints/scripts to launch my applications.

I've noticed that when I work on multiple projects under /apps that the BUNDLE_GEMFILE value does not change as I move from project to project. Shouldn't bundler know which gemfile to use based on which directory I am executing from? Or do I need to manually adjust BUNDLE_GEMFILE each time I switch projects? Thanks!

Comment: `bundle` commands default to the `Gemfile` in the current directory.  You shouldn't normally need to set `$BUNDLE_GEMFILE`.  You might find tools like `rvm` or even Bundler itself to be more convenient ways to get Ruby-based development environments that work with your local files.

Comment: Ok, I created a new container, went to each project and ran 'bundler update', and all of the sudden I see a Gemfile.lock in each directory. I also don't see a BUNDLE_GEMFILE path listed when I run 'bundler config'. This seems to indicate to me that everything is working now (and that it IS defaulting to the cwd for the gemfile)! But why now!! I have had this issue for a while! I have a hunch that once I start developing and hopping from project to project, that this issue will rear its head again...If not, I'll close this issue. Thanks!

Comment: A more typical Docker style is to have only one project in an image, and for `docker run` to just run it.  You might look at using Bundler directly on your host to get an isolated set of gems per project for local day-to-day development, or tools like `rvm` if you need distinct Ruby installations.

Comment: So I'm still seeing this issue pop up. If I delete a project I was working on, I cannot generate a new rails project because it complains that it cannot find the gemfile in the deleted directory. If I move into a different project and run 'bundle update', it seems to fix everything. In the past I've only had one project, deleted it, and then had no other project to go run 'bundle update', and it was extremely difficult to recover bundler/rails behavior (I forgot the details on how I recovered it). It's just strange.